# A close reason for silliness

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I wanted to vote to close some questions because they were silly. Since there was no appropriate close category I did not vote to close. We need a close reason for this. Silliness might equate to extremely and unquestionably obvious, why would such a thing be needed at all, or just playing games with the site (which I have done).

Having a close reason as "silly" would not work, so an appropriate adjective is needed such as:

- unimportant
- too trivial
- answer too obvious

Comment: maybe fatuous :)

Comment: I haven't seen silly questions, can you give examples what do you mean? Silly is too rude and subjective.

Comment: You can read a couple of mine! We would not use the word "silly" as I explained in my original statement, but something alluding to triviality.

Comment: Your questions are not silly or obvious

Comment: I have also seen people refer to garbage and crap on the site, and say we need to work to get rid of it. How subjective is that? Having a silliness reason does not mean anyone must use it, but, it would be nice to have on occasion. Seeing it used might inspire people to be less silly. My silly questions were satirical, actually, hoping to draw attention to silliness.

Comment: These questions were provocative?

Comment: The one about deodorant especially. Or whether my front end needs alignment. The questions are not provocative, but silly, not needing to be asked to begin with, wasting disk space and attention span.

Answer (score 9):

**No**. [A close vote is not a super-downvote](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one). There is no limitation on how silly a question can be.

Downvote silliness all you like, but remember silliness, alone, is *not* a reason to close a question.

Answer (score 3):

Use a custom close reason.

Also, since 'trivial' and 'obvious' are subjective, I *really* wouldn't want to see either of them on a rubber stamp.

Comment: They are just words in a list to help people fill out the form. Have you never seen a question as silly? What are the chances most people also the the question as silly? Everything is subjective, ultimately, but we do have close reasons nonetheless.

Comment: Of course I've seen silly questions here, but as Mr. Cartaino pointed out on some of my earlier close reason requests, creating a rubber stamp is dangerous.